# laravel paypal rest sdk returning 400 on setTotal

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Im trying to add a set price on a item but when i submit the request i get

```
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.
```

here is the code

```
$amountPayable = 5.00;
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('CAD')
        ->setTotal($amountPayable);
```

i know setTotal is the cause but idk why.

Comment: Log the request and response JSON.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated PayPal-PHP-SDK, which uses the deprecated v1/payments API.

Change your integration to use the current [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK), which uses the current v2/checkout/orders API.